# How to achieve Greek keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard-layout, unicode

I would like to have some easy way to type Greek letters. The most appropriate solution is probably to use US keyboard layout with Greek letters on 3rd level, but I could not find any.

Do I have to create my custom layout? If yes, can you provide a tutorial link?

P.S. I am using Arch with Gnome

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you only need it it Gnome, follow this Arch Wiki article
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_Xorg#Switching_between_keyboard_layouts

If you need it in the terminal as well see this one as well https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_console